# como hacer para que se ejecute una funcion despues de un determinado tiempo? React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

me gustaria hacer que una funcion se ejecute cada 20 dias. Lo que se me ocurre es usar un `setTimeOut` pero no se si seria la forma correcta de hacerlo, ya que utiliza milisegundos y tendria que poner demasiados numeros. No se si habria otro metodo para que js sepa cuantos dias pasaron y ejecute la funcion. Espero que puedan ayudarme.

Muchas gracias!!!

Comment: Eso no te funcionaria, a menos que quieras tener la pagina abierta durante 20 dias seguidos, de lo contrario no funcionará. Quizas nos puedas contar que es lo que pretendes hacer y depronto te podemos brindar alguna alternativa.

Comment: el proyecto es un calendario que se por semana y loseventos (de momento) se guardarian en el localStorage. Mi idea era que para evitar que se llene la memoria del localStorage crear una funcion que cada 20 dias borre todo lo guardado

Comment: Entonces lo que puedes hacer es que una vez se inicie la app, borre los eventos creados hace mas de 20 dias